# Multiple RewriteRules for single RewriteCond

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have this code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com:8080
RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain.com:8080%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?domain\.com:8080$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\.domain\.com:8080$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([0-9-]+)/?(.*)?\.html$ view.php?prefix=%1&cat=$1&id=$2&title=$3 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?domain\.com:8080$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\.domain\.com:8080$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?((index|news|photos|videos|articles)\.html)?$ categories.php?prefix=%1&cat=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?domain\.com:8080$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\.domain\.com:8080$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(index\.html)/?$ category_index.php?prefix=%1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com:8080 [NC]
RewriteRule  .?  -  [S=3]
RewriteRule ^(tube|login|register|facebook|logout)\.html$ $1.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^page/([A-Za-z0-9-]+).html$ page.php?prefix=$1 
RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml sitemap.php [QSA,L]


</IfModule>
```

i want `login.html` and all sisters open only on `www.domain.com/login.html` and give 404 error if opened on `games.domain.com/login.html`

and also `RewriteRule  .?  -  [S=3]` not work for me, i'm tried to do

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?domain\.com:8080$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\.domain\.com:8080$ [NC]
RewriteRule  .?  -  [S=3]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([0-9-]+)/?(.*)?\.html$ view.php?prefix=%1&cat=$1&id=$2&title=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?((index|news|photos|videos|articles)\.html)?$ categories.php?prefix=%1&cat=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(index\.html)/?$ category_index.php?prefix=%1 [L,QSA]
```

its not working here and here

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com:8080 [NC]
RewriteRule  .?  -  [S=3]
RewriteRule ^(tube|login|register|facebook|logout)\.html$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 2):

This condition is wrong:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?domain\.com:8080 [NC]
```

As you can only match host name using `HTTP_HOST` variable without port. To make it work use this compound condition:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}:%{SERVER_PORT} !^(www\.)?domain\.com:8080$ [NC]
```